# Getting data for given day from pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe `df` as below:

```
date1               item_id
2000-01-01 00:00:00    0
2000-01-01 10:01:00    1
2000-01-01 00:02:00    2
2000-01-01 00:03:00    3
2000-01-01 00:04:00    4
2000-01-01 00:05:00    5
2000-01-01 00:06:00    6
2000-01-01 12:07:00    7
2000-01-02 00:08:00    8
2000-01-02 00:00:00    0
2000-01-02 00:01:00    1
2000-01-02 03:02:00    2
2000-01-02 00:03:00    3
2000-01-02 00:04:00    4
2000-01-02 00:05:00    5
2000-01-02 04:06:00    6
2000-01-02 00:07:00    7
2000-01-02 00:08:00    8
```

I need the data for single day i.e. 1st Jan 2000. Below query gives me the correct result. But is there a way it can be done just by passing "2000-01-01"?

```
result= df[(df['date1'] > '2000-01-01 00:00') & (df['date1'] < '2000-01-01 23:59')]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`partial string indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#partial-string-indexing), but need `DatetimeIndex` first:

```
df = df.set_index('date1')['2000-01-01']
print (df)
                     item_id
date1                       
2000-01-01 00:00:00        0
2000-01-01 10:01:00        1
2000-01-01 00:02:00        2
2000-01-01 00:03:00        3
2000-01-01 00:04:00        4
2000-01-01 00:05:00        5
2000-01-01 00:06:00        6
2000-01-01 12:07:00        7
```

Another solution is convert datetimes to strings by [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df['date1'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') == '2000-01-01']
print (df)
                date1  item_id
0 2000-01-01 00:00:00        0
1 2000-01-01 10:01:00        1
2 2000-01-01 00:02:00        2
3 2000-01-01 00:03:00        3
4 2000-01-01 00:04:00        4
5 2000-01-01 00:05:00        5
6 2000-01-01 00:06:00        6
7 2000-01-01 12:07:00        7
```

Comment: Hehe nice but now you copied my solution (although I know you didn't in reality!)

Comment: @AntonvBR - dont worry, only principe same, but solution is different :)

Answer (score 2):

The other alternative would be to create a mask:

```
df[df.date1.dt.date.astype(str) == '2000-01-01']
```

Full example:

```
import pandas as pd

data = '''\
date1                  item_id
2000-01-01T00:00:00    0
2000-01-01T10:01:00    1
2000-01-01T00:02:00    2
2000-01-01T00:03:00    3
2000-01-01T00:04:00    4
2000-01-01T00:05:00    5
2000-01-01T00:06:00    6
2000-01-01T12:07:00    7
2000-01-02T00:08:00    8
2000-01-02T00:00:00    0
2000-01-02T00:01:00    1
2000-01-02T03:02:00    2'''

df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(data), sep='\s+', parse_dates=['date1'])

res = df[df.date1.dt.date.astype(str) == '2000-01-01']
print(res)
```

Returns:

```
                date1  item_id
0 2000-01-01 00:00:00        0
1 2000-01-01 10:01:00        1
2 2000-01-01 00:02:00        2
3 2000-01-01 00:03:00        3
4 2000-01-01 00:04:00        4
5 2000-01-01 00:05:00        5
6 2000-01-01 00:06:00        6
7 2000-01-01 12:07:00        7
```

---

**Or**

```
import datetime
df[df.date1.dt.date == datetime.date(2000,1,1)]
```